# jQuery get content from dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input

i have a problem with getting value of dynamically created input that i am creating from content of a  in a table. It is used for edit action but... i can't get its value when i finish editing. Here is the part of my code:

```
$(document).delegate('button#editContact', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $('input[name="firstName"]').val();
    alert(firstName);
    var lastName = $('input[name="lastName"]').val();
    alert(lastName);
});
```

And 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XZNQS/4/)
is whole code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in jQuery, in vanilla javascript you can use getElementsByTagName.
ex:

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++){
   var id = allInputs[i].id;
   alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
}
```

I used this approach when generating n dynamically generated inputs.

Hope it helps

Comment: My whole project is written in jQuery. So its good to be in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and here it is: [Superlive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh5mGR2GyLY) you can use it for every element that is created no matter when, just have to pass the selector.